# Data Toggle Information Passing

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Hello I have django project where I list images and I want that if someone click on one image it gets bigger. It works that a new little window is appearing but because I am getting the image source via template tagging I was not able to pass the information to the window. I will post my template and hope that I was understandable. Thank you very much.

html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">{{lecturer.lecturer}}</h1>
    <hr>
    {% for i in distribution%}
    <div class='img1'>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalimg" href="#">
        <img name="pic" src="{{ i.distribution.url }}">                     --->I am clicking here
        </a>
        <p style="text-align:center;">{{i.lecture}} | {{i.semester}}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalimg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <img name="pic" src="{{ i.distribution.url }}">  ---> but I could not pass i
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, you closed your loop in the container and so the data is not available in the `exampleModalimg` div.  Place the `exampleModalimg` div inside the loop and it should work.

Comment: then I am getting only the first picture bigger no matter what I am clicking

Comment: thats is because the id of the element is the same, add something like`exampleModalimg-{{i.distribution.id}}` to the id of the element as well as the data-target.